# Using ffmpeg to export mp4 binary metadata frame by frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mp4 file that has a video and a metadata stream. Using the command `ffmpeg -i .\myfile.MP4 -map 0:1 -c copy -copy_unknown -f rawvideo .\myfile.bin` I was able to extract the data from the metadata stream as a single binary file.

I am now interested in having ffmpeg export data from this same metadata stream in a similar way to the frame-by-frame export for video streams. That is, I would like to obtain a list of binary files, each containing a separate sample from the metadata stream.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the segment muxer.